# elm and database transactions

Tags: php, database, elm

I have a static website where all the content is rendered by elm.

Right now all the data is hard-coded into the elm source code. In the future I would like to add a small amount of database interaction to the project.

The web server I use support MySQL databases and PHP.

I was thinking it would be nice to be able to use the `get` function in the [elm Http package](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-http/3.0.0/Http) to point to a php script on the server, which would query the database, and return json data that my elm program could interpret and render.

I would like to know if:

- This approach is possible
- There is a better (more convenient or correct) way to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe is a good way to do it. See this chapter in elm-tutorial that covers this http://www.elm-tutorial.org/080_fetching_resources/cover.html

As an alternative you could seed the data in the html and pass it via ports.

Comment: That link is broken. Here is something similar from the official guide: https://guide.elm-lang.org/effects/json.html

Answer (score 1):

That approach is very much possible (I do the same to access TCP connections on my server by using a GET request to a CGI module on the same server as the web page).

This is, as far as I know, the best way to do this for all client side pages. I work for a company and we use PHP, Node and MySQL, with about half of the scripts in Node and the other half in PHP, all of them just talk between the front end and the database.